# Decay of the Fourier Transform of non-integrable functions.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

An integrable function generally means an $L^1$ function. If we stick to functions from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$, then $f$ is integrable means that
$$
\|f\|_1 = \int\limits_\mathbb{R} |f(t)|dt < \infty.
$$
In this case the Fourier transform of $f$ which we denote by $F$ is well defined as an integral and we have the standard inequality (for $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$),
$$
|F(\xi)| \leq \|f\|_1.
$$

If $f$ takes on positive values, then I expect we can modify the proof of the Rieman-Lebesgue lemma to show that
$$
|F(\xi)| \leq \frac{\|f\|_1}{|\xi|}
$$
for $|\xi| \gg 0$.

**My Question** is whether analogous bounds exist if we assume just that
$$
\int\limits_\mathbb{R} f(t) dt < \infty
$$
and not necessarily that $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Thank you.

Comment: "Assume just that $\int f<\infty$" is very unclear: If $f\notin L^1$ then what is $\int f$ in the first place? Doesn't matter since the preliminary result that you "expect" you can prove is false...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result you want to extend to the case $f\not\ge0$ is already false for $f>0$:

> > There exists $f\in L^1(\Bbb R)$ with $f>0$ such that $\hat f(\xi)\ne O\left(\frac1{|\xi|}\right).$

I "knew" immediately that $f>0$ could not give that bound on $\hat f$, but I thought the counterexample might be tricky. No, we can do this with no work at all:

Say $f>0$, $\int f<\infty$, $\int f^2=\infty$. *Since* $\hat f$ is continuous, if we had $\hat f(\xi)=O\left(\frac1{|\xi|}\right)$ it would follow that $\hat f\in L^2$, hence $f\in L^2$, contradiction.

Comment: Yes, if you want simple examples that decay at any chosen rate $a\in(0,1)$, you can take $f(x) = \frac{1}{|x|^{1-a}} \,\varphi(x)$ with $\varphi\in C^\infty_c$ nonnegative. Then
$$
\widehat f = \frac{c}{|x|^{a}} * \widehat\varphi \underset{x\to \infty}{∼} \frac{c}{|x|^{a}}
$$